# Module "'ngFacebook' is not available!" error while using ngFacebook service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, facebook

Hi I am trying to integrate facebook with my angular js web app. For that I am using ngFacebook service in angular js.
But when I executing my app I am getting an error

```
"Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module tveWebApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngFacebook due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ngFacebook' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument".
```

I installed ngFacebook service using the command "bower install ng-facebook".

And here is my code

```
angular.module('tveWebApp', ['ngFacebook'
    ]).config(['$facebookProvider', function($facebookProvider){

        $facebookProvider.setAppId('709438295835304');
        $facebookProvider.setPermissions("email,user_likes");
        $facebookProvider.setVersion("v2.3");
    }]).run(['$rootScope',
        function($rootScope) {
              (function(){
                 if (document.getElementById('facebook-jssdk')) {return;}
                 var firstScriptElement = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];

                 var facebookJS = document.createElement('script'); 
                 facebookJS.id = 'facebook-jssdk';

                 facebookJS.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';

                 firstScriptElement.parentNode.insertBefore(facebookJS, firstScriptElement);
               }());
}]);
```

My controller

```
  $scope.isLoggedIn = false;
  $scope.login = function() {
    $facebook.login().then(function() {
      refresh();
    });
  }
  function refresh() {
    $facebook.api("/me").then( 
      function(response) {
        $scope.welcomeMsg = "Welcome " + response.name;
        $scope.isLoggedIn = true;
      },
      function(err) {
        $scope.welcomeMsg = "Please log in";
      });
  }

  refresh();
```

my view

```
    <button type="button" ng-click="login()" ng-hide="isLoggedIn" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">
        Login
    </button>
    <div id="fb-root">
```

How can I solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you remember to add the script path to Facebook.js file in your index.html?

Comment: If an answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted, thanks

Comment: I will do that Nexus.Thanks for your help.I have solved my problem. Actually  I added this directive as a bower component, but I forget to add the dependency in bower.json file.Now I added the dependency ("ng-facebook": "~0.1.6"), and my code is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Add the file in your index.html:

```
<script src="link//to//ng-facebook.js"></script>
```